# How to load predefined docker image using puppet..?

Tags: tar, docker, puppet

I am having an docker image named image.tar, which was created by using 'docker save' command from another machine and copied to puppet master. I am using ['garethr-docker'](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-docker) module to configure nodes. How can i load my image.tar in nodes using puppet..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `site.pp` manifest that I used to install docker from a local repository and the nginx container from a tar, all done in a vagrant instance:

```
node /^local/ {
  package { 'docker': }
  class { 'docker':
    manage_package   => false,
  }
  docker::image{ 'nginx':
    docker_tar   => '/vagrant/nginx-v1.11.5.tar',
  }
}
```